# ASP.NET Core -> Label asp-for not returning label text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For some reason I can not get my label to render it just displays the text box. I am new to programming and .NET Core. I reckon this is a simple of mistake of mine. I just cant see it. Any ideas please?

**Model**

```
namespace Web.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
        public string MapCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```html
@model Web.Models.Item
    
<div class="container">
    <form asp-action="NewRecord" method="post" class="form-group" role="form">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Item.Name"></label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input asp-for="Item.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to see something wrong with that. What actually does it display in html? To complement that can you try placing that label in the same div as the input?

Comment: try just only the name `<label asp-for="Name"></label>`

Comment: I have tried just the Name property and ive just added a screenshot of what I see.

Comment: Please update your revised code, we suggest you use F12 to view the label html Elements code rendered on the page, and take a screenshot for our reference.

Answer (score 0):

In your view if you set explicitly model then you only need to put name of property from that model. That means your **view** should looks like following code and you don't need and you cannot explicitly put **Item.Name**:

```
@model Web.Models.Item

<div class="container">
<form asp-action="NewRecord" method="post" class="form-group" role="form">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

On other side if you want to use some custom name you should use annotations:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Hovewer, probably here you want to use View Models instead directly Models then you need some UI validation, custom names etc. Follow this example and try to understand logic.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Some name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Map code")]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string MapCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Emin, even with just name its not pulling through the label text. Maybe I have a bigger problem with my app :(
Ill start working through it to see what could be wrong.